# Gulp copy list of folders with contents

Tags: javascript, gulp

I would like to copy a list of folders to a destination with gulp

So far i've come up with a working solution, but its far from performant.

The structure of my directory is like this:

- App

  - src
  - web
  - some files...

and i would like to copy it to

- build

  - src
  - web
  - the files

The code i am using to accomplish this is:

```
var paths = [path.app + '/src/', path.app + '/app/'].concat(path.assets);

paths.forEach(function(value, index){
    // value.replace(path.app, path.build);

    gulp.src(value + '/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(value.replace(path.app, path.build)));
});
```

Where the assets are my files (or other directories)
However there is a loop and no clear return value. I am wondering if there is a more performant way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here (where is your gulp task definition for example?), but it seems like you just want to copy everything below `App` to the `build` folder while preserving directory structure.

If that's the case, you don't have to loop over the files and replace folder names yourself. Gulp does it for you:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('App/**')
               .pipe( gulp.dest('build') );
});
```

Everything before the `**` is automatically stripped from the path of files written to `build`, so you end up with `build/src`, `build/web`, etc ...

Comment: Adding `/**` rather than `/**/*` also copied the directory and fixed my problem, thank you!

Comment: totally missing thins info everywhere - just using `**` to copy whole dir - thx